# Are there ordinals $\alpha,\beta$ such that $\alpha+\beta \neq \beta+\alpha$ but $\alpha2+\beta2=\beta2+\alpha2$?

Tags: ordinals

I know that if $\alpha+\beta=\beta+\alpha$, then by associativity $\alpha2+\beta2=\beta2+\alpha2$. Was wondering if the reverse holds?

Edit:

It can't be possible.
$\alpha+\beta < \beta+\alpha$.
$\alpha+\alpha+\beta+\beta \leq \alpha+\beta+\alpha+\beta < \alpha+\beta+\beta+\alpha \leq \beta+\alpha+\beta+\alpha \leq \beta+\beta+\alpha+\alpha$

Comment: I don't think $\alpha2+\beta2=(\alpha+\beta)2$. For example, $\omega \cdot 2+1 \cdot 2 \neq (\omega+1) \cdot 2 = \omega \cdot 2 + 1$

Comment: What is your definition of $\alpha \cdot \beta$? The one I know is that it is the ordinal of $\alpha \times \beta$ under the lexigraphic ordering: if $(s,t), (x,y) \in \alpha \times \beta$, then $(s, t) < (x, y)$ if $s < x$ or if $s = x$ and $t < y$. By that definition, $\omega \cdot 2 + 1\cdot 2 = (\omega + 1)\cdot 2 = \omega + 2$. And it is $2 \cdot \omega= \omega + \omega \ne \omega \cdot 2$.

Comment: Oh my definition is the reverse of yours. So it is defined inductively on the right.

Comment: That makes sense then. I think you may need to get used to your definition being reversed in most writings. I don't recall seeing it defined that way before. But I may well be wrong. I have found before that a convention ($0\notin \Bbb N$) I thought universal for years had in fact coexisted with an apparently wider-used convention ($0\in \Bbb N$) that may also be older.

Comment: Maybe if one considers finite ordinals?

Comment: It may be a good idea to [self-answer your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).